# Class vendorname\modulename\Model\ResourceModel\Wishlistnotifcation\CollectionFactory does not exist

Tags: magento-2.1, grid, uicomponent, admin-controller

I am creating admin grid and show data on admin grid using ui component. i have created model resource model and collection.

**view\adminhtml\layout\notification_notification_notification.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="notification_notification_notification_listing"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**view\adminhtml\ui_component\notification_notification_notification_listing.xml**

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../Magento/Ui/etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">notification_notification_notification_listing.notification_notification_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">notification_notification_notification_listing.notification_notification_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">notification_columns</item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="notification_notification_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magenerds\WishlistNotification\Ui\DataProvider\WishlistnotificationGridDataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">notification_notification_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <container name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <filters name="listing_filters" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Filters">


        </filters>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">

        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">notification_notification_listing.notification_listing.notification_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">notification_listing.notification_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">bottom</item>
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="20" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">20</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="30" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">30</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="50" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">50</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="100" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="number">100</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">100</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="200" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="number">200</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">200</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </paging>
    </container>
    <columns name="notification_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">notification_listing.notification_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">notification_listing.notification_listing.notification_columns.actions</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">applyAction</item>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                            <item name="1" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="controlVisibility" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">notification_listing.notification_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root}</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                </item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="customer_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                </item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Id</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="wishlist_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                </item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Wishlist Id</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="wishlistitem_id" class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Price">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                </item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Wishlist item Id</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="product_id" class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Price">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                </item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product Id</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">60</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="customer_name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                </item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer name</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">70</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="customer_mail">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                </item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer email</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">80</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="added_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Added at</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">90</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

    </columns>
</listing>
```

**Controller\Adminhtml\Notification**

```
class Notification extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $_resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Index action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
        $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->setActiveMenu('Magenerds_WishlistNotification::wishlist_mail');
        $resultPage->addBreadcrumb(__('Wishlist Mail Notification'), __('Wishlist MailNotification'));
        $resultPage->addBreadcrumb(__('Wishlist Mail Notification'), __('Wishlist MailNotification'));
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Wishlist Mail Notification'));

        return $resultPage;
    }

    /**
     * Check for is allowed
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Magenerds_WishlistNotification::wishlist_mail');
    }
}
```

**etc\di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="WishlistnotificationGridDataProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">Magenerds\Wishlist_Notification\Model\ResourceModel\Wishlistnotifcation\Collection</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Magenerds\Wishlist_Notification\Model\ResourceModel\Wishlistnotifcation\Collection">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">wishlist_notification</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Magenerds\Wishlist_Notification\Model\ResourceModel\Wishlistnotifcation</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Collection">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <!--data provider name which used in grid ui component file -->
                <item name="notification_notification_notification_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Magenerds\Wishlist_Notification\Model\ResourceModel\Wishlistnotifcation\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Ui\DataProvider\WishlistnotificationGridDataProvider.php**

```
class WishlistnotificationGridDataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{
    /**
     * Notification collection
     *
     * @var \Magenerds\WishlistNotification\Model\ResourceModel\Notification\Collection
     */
    protected $_collection;

    /**
     * Construct
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AddFieldToCollectionInterface[] $addFieldStrategies
     * @param \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AddFilterToCollectionInterface[] $addFilterStrategies
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        Magenerds\WishlistNotification\Model\ResourceModel\Wishlistnotifcation\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
        $this->_collection = $collectionFactory->create();
    }

    /**
     * Get data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        if (!$this->getCollection()->isLoaded()) {
            $this->getCollection()->addFieldToSelect('*')->load();
        }
        $items = $this->getCollection()->toArray();

        return [
            'totalRecords' => $this->getCollection()->getSize(),
            'items' => array_values($items['items']),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magenerds\WishlistNotification\Model\ResourceModel\Notification\Collection
     */
    public function getCollection()
    {
        return $this->_collection;
    }
```

anyone can help me regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Ui\DataProvider\WishlistnotificationGridDataProvider.php**, change:

```
Magenerds\WishlistNotification\Model\ResourceModel\Notification\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
```

To:

```
\Magenerds\WishlistNotification\Model\ResourceModel\Notification\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
```

It just needs the backslash at the start.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the class `Magenerds\Wishlist_Notification\Model\ResourceModel\Wishlistnotifcation\Collection`

```
<?php


namespace [VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Model\ResourceModel\Wishlistnotifcation;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init([VendorName]\[Module_Name]\Model\Wishlistnotifcation::class, '[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Model\ResourceModel\Wishlistnotifcation');
    }
}
```

Comment: i h ave added class ..but its not working for me ....